# Error creating Exchange mailbox, initials field to long

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I used adsiedit to enlarge the rangeUpper of the "Initials" attribute in AD from 6 to 12 chars. My DC is running 2008R2.

Now I want to create a Exchange 2010 mailbox for this user, but it seems that Exchange also checks the length of the field. It throws this error: "Error:
The length of the property is too long. The maximum length is 6 and the length of the value provided is 7."

Exchange is correct about this, normally it is never longer than 6 chars. Because of the edit in the AD schema it can now contain 12 chars. How to make Exchange ignore this unusual setting that I did?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Change in schema didn't replicatie to all dc's yet. Waited 30 minutes, then Exchange accepted the larger initials field.